# Show results on cards or boxes

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I display this result:

```
Your result:
var1: 1,4,3
var2: 2,5,6
```

into like this:

```
Your result:
 ______________
|var1          |
|--------------|
|1 4 3         |
|______________|
```

Similarly for other variables, like var2, etc...
Here's my code, which allows the result to be displayed as in the first variant.

```
<div class="section-heading text-center">
                    <h2>Your result:</h2>          
                    @foreach ($variables_json as $variable => $value)
                    <h5>{{ $variable }}: {{ implode(", ", $value) }}</h5>
                    @endforeach        
                    <form method="post" id="form" action="{{route('randomizeVariables.store')}}" name="form" 
                    class="form text-center" data-response-message-animation="slide-in-left" 
                    novalidate>
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-alternate align-center">Try again</button>                        
                        <a href="/randomizeValue" id="destroySession" type="submit" 
                        class="btn btn-lg btn-alternate align-center">Return</a>    
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always have the same number of values to display, use a table with cells and rows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name
    <th>Val 1
    <th>Val 2
  </tr>
    @foreach ($variables_json as $variable => $values)
       <tr>
       <td>{{ $variable }}</td>
       @foreach($values as $val)
           <td>{{$val}}</td>
       @endforeach
      </tr>
    @endforeach  
</table>
```

If the value counts are random, you can take advantage of Laravel's `$loop` value within the foreach with spaces in between, using any kind of `<div>` class to separate the name from the value:

```
    @foreach ($variables_json as $variable => $values)
       <div class='col-md-4'>{{ $variable }}</div>
       <div class='col-md-8'>
       @foreach($values as $val)
           {{$val}}
           {!! $loop->last? "": "  &nbsp; " !!}
       @endforeach
      </div>
  @endforeach
```

I renamed `$value` to `$values` as it looks like that is an array.  Might make it a little easier to read and to know there is need to implode or loop on that set of values.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your help is very useful. But how can I make the tables more visible? Add something to the css or something else? They're currently transparent.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  You can add css to do whatever styling you like on the table.  If you are using bootstrap, `class = "table"` is built in, but there are tons more.  you can stripe the lines, or even make some of the `<td>`s in red, or whatever you wish using css.